# Is it possible to redirect VPN traffic by Apache

Tags: vpn, apache-2.4, http, proxypass

There is a web server in my lab with Apache. Only 80 port is opened.
I can install software on it. Is it possible to install some VPN tools and redirect the VPN traffic by Apache?

In another words, my VPN client sends a request like "https://webserver/VPN", Apache receives it and passes the data to VPN server in the same machine, and then forwards the reponse to my VPN client. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use mod_proxy to proxy pass requests to any service then the response from that service will go through apache and back to the client

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html

Your VPN server would have to talk http since that is the protocol that it would get getting from apache